# Mismatch in number of detected contours in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv

As per the documentation, the function `cvFindContours()` returns the number of retrieved contours from the binary image input. However when I'm running a loop over all the contours the number of detected contours is drastically less.

A possible reason would be that child contours of a parent, as well as holes are being counted in the return value of the function. Even so this number is not matching a reasonable eye-estimate of the pictures used by me.

The return value in this case is 92, whereas in traversing all the contours there are 15 distinct contours.

Here's the code:

```
int n = cvFindContours(img_canny_mop, mem, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
printf("No of retrieved contours = %d",n);
for (ptr = contours; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->h_next) 
{
        ext_color = CV_RGB( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 ); //randomly coloring different contours
        cvDrawContours(cc_color, ptr, ext_color, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));          
        //display( cc_color, "CCs");
        n_cont++;
}
cvSaveImage("CC_colors.jpg",cc_color);
printf("\nNo of contours = %d",n_cont);
```

The images are:

Input: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/cannymop.jpg/

Randomly colored contours: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/cccolors.jpg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the documentation [here](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Ebouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_ImageProcessing.htm). The key part being the following.

> The pointer firstContour is filled by
> the function. It will contain pointer
> to the first most outer contour or
> NULL if no contours is detected (if
> the image is completely black). Other
> contours may be reached from
> firstContour using h_next and v_next
> links.

May be you need to check the number of v_next for each h_next (or vice versa).